# Is square of a VMO function in VMO

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

We say a function $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ is in $\mathrm{BMO}(\mathbb{R})$ if

$$\|f\|_{\mathrm{BMO}}=\sup_{I}\frac{1}{|I|}\int\limits_I |f(y)-f_I|\, dy<\infty$$ for all intervals $I\subset\mathbb{R},$ where  $f_I$ is the average value of $f$: $$f_I=\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I f(y)\, dy.$$

$f\in \mathrm{VMO}(\mathbb{R})$ if $f \in\mathrm{BMO}$ and
$$\lim_{|I|\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{|I|}\int_I|f(y)-f_I|\, dy\rightarrow 0. $$

For more details, see [Bounded mean oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation).

Some facts that maybe useful

- UC $\cap$ BMO $\subset$ VMO, where UC means uniformly continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$.
- VMO is the closure of UC $\cap$ BMO in BMO.

My question is

> 1.If $f\in $ VMO, is $f^2\in$ VMO? (If yes, next question is trivial; if not, please see next question)

> 2.If $\omega\in A_\infty$,[A_p weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckenhoupt_weights#Weights_and_BMO) and $\log \omega\in$ VMO, is $(\log \omega)^2 \in$ VMO?

My try:

Divide $f=f_1+f_2$, where $f_1\in \mathrm{UC}\cap \mathrm{BMO},\ \|f_2\|_{BMO}<\epsilon$. But I can't go on next. I am not sure it is correct, if not, could you give me a counterexample? Thanks very much.

Comment: Also on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394515/is-square-of-a-vmo-function-in-vmo)